# Cosine problem for use in fourier series

Tags: trigonometry

If $k$ is positive $\cos(k\pi) = (-1)^k$

If $k$ is negative $\cos(k\pi) = $ ?

Comment: $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Since,
for integer $k$,
$(-1)^k
=(-1)^{-k}
$
and
$\cos(k \pi)
=\cos(-k \pi)
$,
all these are equal:
$(-1)^k
=(-1)^{-k}
=\cos(k \pi)
=\cos(-k \pi)
$.